# Number of words in containing $0,1$

Tags: combinatorics

> How many words of length $n$ in $0,1$ are there such that the words has no consecutive $1$'s  and the first and last position cannot be occupied by $1$?

I think answer would come with the help of recursion relation between the words!

Comment: There are two possible interpretations of the restriction about first, last: (i) neither can be $1$ or (ii) they cannot both be $1$. Under interpretation (i), apart from the cases $n=0$ or $n=1$, we are at a standard length $n-2$, no consecutive $1$'s problem. There is a standard recurrence. For interpretation (ii), a similar idea will wor.

Comment: @AndréNicolas check Ross Miilikan's answer. Apparently fibonacci. :D

Comment: Sure, for book-ended by $0$'s it reduces to a standard problem. If we use interpretation (ii) (the wording is not clear) then we need to modify things a bit.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am not talking about the actual solution, I am just amazed that *fibonacci*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the requirement is that neither the first nor the last is $1$, First, make the problem refer to words of length $n-2$ (and tack the first and last zero on at the end).  Then a word of length $n-2$ can come from a word of length $n-3$ with a $0$ on the end or from a word of length $n-4$ with $01$ on the end...

Comment: And fibonacci showed up.

Comment: hallelujah! praise fibonacci!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n$ be the number of such words. Clearly $f_1=1$, namely, 0. For $n=2$ we can enumerate the options 00, 01, 10, 11, and pretty clearly see that it's got to be 00, so $f_2=1$. Now for $n>2$, how can we obtain such words? They all must end in 00 or 010 and satisfy your conditions. Then if you chop off the last 0, it is such a word of length $n-1$. If it ends in 010 then chopping off the 10 gives you such a word of length $n-2$. So for $n>2$, $f_n = f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$. Hopefully that last relationship is familiar to you.